# How to average the last 5 nonblank, nonzero value in a row in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I run a disc golf league and in order to track handicaps we take an average of the last 5 rounds played. I currently have the player name in column A, the handicap in B, # of rounds played in C, best round in D, then a manual average of the last 5 in E. then the next 33 columns are the weekly scores for each player.

I'm wondering if there is a formula that can capture the last 5 (or less) weeks scores and average them, accounting for the fact that not every player plays every week, so there are lots of blank cells.

Comment: Is the most recent week in `F` or is `F` the oldest week?

Comment: F is the most recent week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Most Recent to Oldest

If the date of the weeks in the range `F:AM` decrease as the column number increases then these formulas will work

**Example:**

| F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Week 33 | Week 32 | Week 31 | Week 30 |

##### Single Row Formula

- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) removes any empty cells from columns F-AM (33 columns)
- [ARRAY_CONSTRAIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036) limits the array to a maximum of 5 columns
- [AVERAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093615) gets the average of the values in the array

```
=AVERAGE(
  ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
    FILTER(F1:AM1, F1:AM1<>""),
    1, 5))
```

##### BYROW Formula

- [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) maps each row in the range `F2:AM100`, one-by-one, into a [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function
- [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function applies a formula against each set of values it is passed, using the arbitrarily named variable `r` to represent the mapped values in the formula
- the **Single Row Formula** (above) is adapted simply by removing the range that was specified and replacing it with the named variable `r`

```
=BYROW(F1:AM100, LAMBDA(r, 
   AVERAGE(
    ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
      FILTER(r, r<>""),
        1,5))))
```

## Oldest to Most Recent

If the date of the weeks in the range `F:AM` increase as the column number increases then these formulas will work.

**Example:**

| F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 | Week 4 |

##### Single Row (Reverse Order) Formula

I created a LAMBDA version to make the formula easier to read, but in the code example showed the non-LAMBDA version as well)

- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) removes any empty cells from columns F-AM (33 columns)
- [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) uses an arbitrarily named variable `r` to represent the [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) function to make it easier to be reused multiple times in the formula
- [COUNTA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991) gives us the number of values in `r`
- [SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) creates a column of numbers starting at 1, incrementing by 1, and increasing until it reaches the number of values in `r`
- [SORTN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624) sorts `r` by using the **reverse** order of the [SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) column and returning a maximum of 5 values
- [AVERAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093615) is then applied to the array

```
=LAMBDA(r, AVERAGE(
    SORTN(TRANSPOSE(r),5,,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(r)),FALSE)))
 (FILTER(F1:AM1, F1:AM1<>""))


# Non-LAMBDA Version

=AVERAGE(
   SORTN(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(F1:AM1, F1:AM1<>"")), 5,,
         SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTER(F1:AM1, F1:AM1<>""))),
         FALSE))
```

##### BYROW Formula (Reverse order)

- [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) maps each row in the range `F2:AM100`, one-by-one, into a [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function
- [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function applies a formula against each set of values it is passed, using the arbitrarily named variable `s` to represent the mapped values in the formula
- the **Single Row (Reverse Order) Formula** (above) is adapted simply by removing the range that was specified and replacing it with the named variable `s`

```
=BYROW(F1:AM100, LAMBDA(s, LAMBDA(r, AVERAGE(
    SORTN(TRANSPOSE(r),5,,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(r)),FALSE)))
 (FILTER(s, s<>""))))


# Adapting with the non-LAMBDA version
# of the Single Row (Reverse Order) 
# Formula instead

=BYROW(F1:AM100, LAMBDA(s, AVERAGE(
    SORTN(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(s, s<>"")), 5,,
          SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTER(s, s<>""))),FALSE))
```

Comment: Thank you!

That first formula (Single Row) is really close to what I am looking for, however I need it to average the last 5 values in the row. Is there a way to modify it to accomplish that?

Comment: [answer updated](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/169777/).  FYI the advantage of the `BYROW` versions is that you define the range once and the single formula will generate the average for all your rows.